# Convergent sequences doubt from Rudin

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

What does the following mean:
The sequence $<1/n>$ converges in $\mathbb R$ (to 0) but fails to converge in the set of all positive real numbers [with $d(x,y) = |x-y|$].

Reading Rudin's Mathematical Analysis. This is from chapter 3: Numerical sequences and series

Comment: Its limit *should* be $0$, but $0$ isn't in the set of all positive numbers.